# How do I remove dark spots on object AFTER baking?

Tags: mesh, faces, lighting, texture-baking, baking

So I baked my object/mesh. but I have these weird polygon shaped dark spots on the edges/borders of my mesh that show even in the rendered preview. Im not sure if it has something to do with the lighting or the object itself. I've tried redoing the bake, I have removed other mesh objects from the scene when im baking so they dont interfere, and I also have no lighting objects within my scene when im baking.

Just fyi: this project is meant to be used as an avatar clothing asset for the game VRChat, if that helps you at all.

[image: zoom out of shirt mesh][[image: close up of issue on shirt mesh2]

**Blend file link:** removed because question was answered.

Also to any future readers, here’s a video to help explain what poles are and why they may cause issues in projects: https://youtu.be/RR989N_rcA4

Comment: pls upload your file

Comment: i have added the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to look too close to the model,just add Edge Split works,you can adjust the angle as you wish.
[image]

But if we look in detail,we can see some sharp lines on the edge.It's hard to remove in this case.
[image]

Because your mesh don't have a loop along the edge,and there are some poles on the edge,so we can't add loop cut or good subdivision there.If you really want a perfect,you should remodel the edge manually.
[image]

A good topology will looks like this
[image]
You can see that there is a loop faces surround the model and no poles,it's a protection for edge rendering.Poles will not cause trouble on the plane,but where there is some bend,poles will look bad.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t quite understand. So are you saying I have to remodel the mesh so that each of the faces are in a single line? Like perfectly side by side?

Comment: I should also mention that I made the mesh in Marvelous Designer then I imported it into Blender and I didn’t realize it poled a lot of the edges. I’m still trying to learn what and how with good Topology.

Comment: Good topology has some basic principles.I recommend a tutorial,you will know why there are dark pots.The tutorial is for C4D and old,but the rules are the same.I think your topology is good escept the edge loop,maybe you can adjust in your MD. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQmNXCOh4MM&t=593s  BTW,it's not all free,you can try to find some similar tutorial.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! You’ve helped me understand the issue a bit better and I will do what you suggested!